# python gives output value of none, when it should be displaying a changed list

Tags: python

i am new to python.  i am making a game similar to tic-tac-toe, but on a larger scale.  i am able to see the grid before user input, but after the user inputs where they want their piece to go the updated grid does not show.
the output will just say none.  im thinking my problem is in how im displaying the board, but i am unsure.Please help

```
print("This is Gomoku Deluxe!")

#starting off with tic-tac-toe

import os

#this is where the code for the game starts
board = []

for i in range(19):
 board.append(["O"] * 19)


#function to print board
def print_board():
    board = []
    for i in range(19):
      board.append(["O"] * 19)
    for row in board:
      print (row)

#function to place player piece
def drop_point(board, row, col, piece):
    board[row][col] = piece

#function checks for empty spot
def valid_location(board, row, col):
    return board[row][col] == 0

# this loop handles user's piece 
print_board()
turn = 0
game_over = False

while not game_over:
    if turn == 0:
      row = int(input("Player 1 Select a row: "))
      col = int(input("Player 1 Select a col: "))

      if valid_location(board, row, col):
          drop_point(board, row, col, 1)

    else:
      row1 = int(input("Player 2 Select a row: "))
      col1 = int(input("Player 2 Select a col: "))

      if valid_location(board, row1, col1):
          drop_point(board, row1, col1, 2)

    print_board()

    turn += 1
    turn = turn % 2
```

Comment: What do you mean by "say none"? Is there an error or is the board just unaffected? It might because you are making a new board everytime you print it.

Comment: The board is unaffected. After a user inputs there spot its supposed to show the board with the given spot marked. Instead it just gives the output None. Im guessing because its reading the zero value as None

Comment: When I run the program im not getting a `None` output. The board is unaffected though. Which i'm looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there were a few errors in your code.

1.) In the `valid_location` function you were checking if the piece was equal to `0` even though you assigned it as `"O"`

2.) In the `print_board` function you were making a new board everytime.

3.) In the `drop_point` function you were only assigning the value to `board` inside the function

Here's some new and improved code:

```
print("This is Gomoku Deluxe!")

#starting off with tic-tac-toe

import os

#this is where the code for the game starts
board = []

for i in range(19):
 board.append([0] * 19)


#function to print board
def print_board(brd):
    for row in brd:
      print (row)

#function to place player piece
def drop_point(brd, row, col, piece):
    brd[row][col] = piece
    return brd

#function checks for empty spot
def valid_location(board, row, col):
    return board[row][col] == 0

# this loop handles user's piece 
print_board(board)
turn = 0
game_over = False

while not game_over:
    if turn == 0:
      row = int(input("Player 1 Select a row: "))
      col = int(input("Player 1 Select a col: "))

      if valid_location(board, row, col):
          board = drop_point(board, row, col, 1)

    else:
      row1 = int(input("Player 2 Select a row: "))
      col1 = int(input("Player 2 Select a col: "))

      if valid_location(board, row1, col1):
          board = drop_point(board, row1, col1, 2)

    print_board(board)

    turn += 1
    turn = turn % 2
```

Comment: thanks for the assist... a friend also pointed out the "o" "0" mistake earlier today.